# Selenium Webdriver.io error message ERROR: Unexpected identifier firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, software-quality

I was developing tests with Webdriver.io which is a javascript API for Selenium webdriver. Running the tests was going smoothly until I was encountering an error when I run the `$ wdio wdio.conf.js` command. The error was

```
>ERROR: Unexpected identifier
firefox
Syntax    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/joe/Desktop/Webtesting/test/test.js:10:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

It can't be an error in the code since I checked out a previous commit and was getting the same error. It seems to be an error in the wdio.conf.js file, specifically in this this line, the error persists even when I change the browser name  to chrome:

```
   capabilities: [{
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instance available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instance gets started at a time.
        maxInstances: 5,
        //
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }],
```

Comment: Have you tried to move maxInstances outside capabilities? Please check the documentation.

Comment: I just tried moving it outside capabilities, it didn't work. My config is pretty much exactly like the documentation. Here is the documentation for reference: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/configurationfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was indeed a syntax error in my own code. I was simply interpreting the error message wrong. The unexpected identifier was not 'firefox', the name of the browser you are using is always logged before the tests begin so it seemed as if it was part of the "unexpected identifier" error. So just look through your own code and find the syntax error, this is not a problem with webdriver.io